# set the attributes in PHP 5

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

In my Zend framework I have two row one rows contains state dropdown with label state and the other contains a text box with label other state. Below is the code:

```
'state' => array('select', array(
            'required' => true,
            'decorators' => $elementDecorators,
            'label' => 'State:',
            'multiOptions' => $values["state"] 
        )),
        'other_state' => array('text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'decorators' => $elementDecorators,
            'label' => 'Other State:',
            'class' => 'other_state', 
        ))
```

Here the other state is set as required. I need it required only when the user select "Other" value from the state drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Client Side:

*jQuery solution:*

Showing your HTML output would have been a help here. But the following will add the attribute required if `other` is selected - this will also enable the input and disable it so the user can only enter something in other state, if they select other:

```
$("#state").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "other"){
        $("#other_state").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#other_state").attr("required", "required");
    }
    else {
        $("#other_state").removeAttr("required");
        $("#other_state").attr("disabled", "true");
    }
});
```

**[See a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUb5X/)**

*The above will do the validation on the clients side - with jQuery, however if the user has javascript turned off, it would allow the user to select other and leave other_state blank!*

---

### Server Side:

*Zend solution:*

What you should also do is add some [validation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html) to the [zend_form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html). However, you can't add them the normal way - if you added a validator to say `other_state` can't be empty - you would have an error when a state is selected and you want it to be empty.

In your form class you could override the isValid call to add your custom validation, see the [discussion here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Form-Setting-element-required-based-on-a-condition-td640447.html): *There is another example on how to do this [here](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2008/12/24/conditional-form-validation-with-zend_form/)*

```
    /** 
    /* override the isValid function of Zend_Form 
    /* to set a required field based on a condition 
     */ 

    public function isValid($value) {
            // Check the key exists in the stack, and if its set to other: 
            if (array_key_exists('state', $value) && $value['state'] == 'other') { 
                    // It is so make sure other_state is a required field:
                    $this->other_state->setRequired(true); 
            } 
            parent::isValid($value); 
    }
```